# How to create CoreData entity in one class and access in another?

Tags: ios, core-data

I am trying to learn the workings of Core Data. So I created an entity with attributes, got the xcdatamodel file and the .h and .m files for my entity. Great.

I also wrote the following code in my app delegate to add data to my entity:

```
TestEntity *newEntity = [NSEntityDescription 
                         insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"TestEntity" 
                         inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

newEntity.entityName = @"temp";

    NSError *savingError = nil;
    if([self.managedObjectContext save:&savingError]){
        NSLog(@"Success");

    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Fail");
    }
```

so far so good. but now i want to access this data, i.e. the entityName, in my main view controller. This is where I am lost. I read source code samples, and most of them say do the following

```
NSError *requestError = nil;
NSFetchRequest *fetchrequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName: @"TestEntity"];
NSArray *entities = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest: fetchrequest error:&requestError];
```

This should give me an array called entities full of TestEntity objects. So I should be able to access the name by saying `entities.entityName`.

But i get an error saying that managedobjectcontext is not a property of this view controller. That makes sense to me, but i cannot figure out what the solution to this is? Do I just have to implement the necessary coredata properties/methods in each class I want to use core data in?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a Core Data question, it's a basic Objective-C question. In order to use `self.managedObjectContext`, `self` must be an instance of a class that has an instance variable (i.e. property in most modern ObjC) called `managedObjectContext`. **And** you need to assign a value to that property if you want to use it.

Adding the property is easy. Just declare it on the class as a property of the appropriate type (here, an `NSManagedObjectContext`). Assigning a value to it depends on the overall structure of your project. In Xcode's project templates the app delegate creates a managed object context. The app delegate also typically has a reference to one or more view controllers. If you're using this common structure, one way to assign the view controller's managed object context property from somewhere in the app delegate. Something similar to

```
self.mainViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

If your app's architecture is different, you'll need to do something else, but what that is will depend on the details of the app.

Answer (score 0):

You have to refer to your AppDelegate. Do it like this:

```
AppDelegate *del = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.managedObjectContext = del.managedObjectContext;
NSError *requestError = nil;
NSFetchRequest *fetchrequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName: @"TestEntity"];
NSArray *entities = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest: fetchrequest error:&requestError];
```